# S:ClientCannot find dispatch method

Tags: php, soap

i facing issue "**S:ClientCannot find dispatch method**" when calling SOAP URL  .

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cai3="http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/" xmlns:="http://schemas.ericsson.com/ema/UserProvisioning/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <cai3:SessionId>*******</cai3:SessionId>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

below result for page :

S:ClientCannot find dispatch method for {http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/}Get